# Как зафиксировать изображение при масштабировании (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

Будьте здоровы уважаемые форумчани.
Болтаются картинки при увеличении с помощью скрипта Jquery.
Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы картинки не дёргались при увеличении.
Пробовал прописывать свойство "absolute" в Css. Не помогло(((

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.image-1').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "24%",
    height: "auto",
    left: "-3.5%",
    top: "-0.4vmax"
  }, 400);
});

   
$('.image-1').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "22%",
    height: "auto",
    left: "0",
    top: ""
  }, 400);
});

});
```

```css
.image-1 {
  width:22%; 22%;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 3% 0 3% 2.1%;
  border-radius: 1vmax;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
   </head>
  
 <body>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt>
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Так нужно просто повесить transition и увеличивать по transform

Comment: Куда повесить)? Это не на Css а на Jquery))

Answer (score 1):

Вот простым css или задача именно на jq?

```css
.image-1 {
  width: 22%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 3% 0 3% 2.1%;
  border-radius: 1vmax;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 300ms
}

.image-1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

```html
<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt>
```

Вот через JQ но не вижу резона подключать ее.

```js
$('.image-1').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'transform': 'scale(1.1) translate(20%, 20%)',
    'zIndex': 2
  });
});


$('.image-1').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'transform': 'scale(1) translate(0, 0)',
    'zIndex': 0
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: ralative;
}

.image-1 {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 22%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 3% 0 3% 2.1%;
  border-radius: 1vmax;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/9pRkvsN/1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Само масштабирование у меня на Jquery. Но картинки дёргаются при увеличении. Как пофиксить эту проблему? Там есть кнопка "Выполнить код" нажмите на неё и вы поймете о чём я.

Comment: Я же говорю что анимация без воздействия на внешний контент осуществляется через transform поэтому анимируйте от нее.

Comment: Если вам не трудно можете привести пример?

Comment: уже кинул, второй translate для примера, почитайте все ее возможности. transform отрабатывается на уровне видеокарты.

Comment: Вы сказали, что не видите резона подключать через Jquery. Почему вы так считаете?

Comment: Ну это все нормально отрабатывает на чистом css

Comment: Совсем не то(((
На Css мне не хочется делать, tranfsorm при анимации немного искажает пиксели картинок.

Comment: Ваш второй пример это все равно, что в Css прописать hover scale. Результат не очень(((